# Using Racket to lookup elements in a list and evaluating those elements occurs in error

Tags: scheme, racket, lookup, implementation, evaluate

I am given the following environment:

```
(define e1 (map (lambda (x y) (list x y))
             '(     x  y  z + - * cons car cdr nil list add)
             (list 10 20 30 + - * cons car cdr '() list add)))
```

I have written a `lookup` procedure that finds if a symbol is in the list, and when true, it returns the procedure/value associated with the symbol:

```
(define (lookup symbol environment)
  (cond
    ((not (symbol? symbol)) (raise "not a symbol" #t))
    ((boolean? (member symbol environment)) (raise "symbol not in environment" #t))
    (else (member symbol environment))))

(define member
  (lambda (ptr lst)
    (cond
      ((null? ptr) #f)
      ((null? lst) #f)
      ((equal? ptr (caar lst)) (cadar lst))
      (else (member ptr (cdr lst))))))
```

Along with this code, I have written an `evaluate` procedure that will take a list that begins with one of the symbols and applies the procedure associated with it to the rest of the list:

```
(define (evaluate expression environment)
  (cond
      ((number? expression)
       expression)
      ((symbol? expression)
       (lookup expression environment))
      ((list? expression)
       (apply (evaluate (car expression) env)
        (list-of-values (cdr expression) environment)))
      (else (raise "cannot be evaluated" #t))))
```

My issue is not when doing:

```
(evaluate '(+ x y) e1)

(evaluate '(* 2 2 2 2 2 (* 2 2 2 2 2)) e1)
```

My issues only occur when doing:

```
(evaluate '(cons 1 2) e1)

(evaluate '(+ 3 (- 10 y) z) e1)

(evaluate '(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))) e1)

(evaluate '(add 1 2) e1)
```

Which gets caught by my exception:

```
"symbol not in environment"
```

It seems to have trouble with the `cons`, `list`, and `add` symbols. I tried making a specific case for those keywords in the `evaluate` procedure and it still is not working.

Edit: Include list-of-values implementation for future use

```
(define (list-of-values exps env)
  (if (null? exps)
      '()
      (cons (evaluate (car exps) env)
          (list-of-values (cdr exps) env))))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't redefine `lookup` before testing the things that worked? (There's a `member` library function that `lookup` will use if you define things in the given order.)

Comment: You haven't provided your `list-of-values` function, but your code runs fine for me if I assume that it is defined as `(lambda (exprs env) (map (lambda (expr) (evaluate expr env)) exprs))`. I also had to change the word `env` to `environment` where it appears in the call to `apply`; `env` isn't defined.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have list-of-values defined. Fixing the `env` to `environment` fixed all of my issues.